# Deleting Firebase child based on its value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My schema looks like this

[image]

How can I delete the node that corresponds to the value `KX1UfoLwTQOGTFHxyguqcl7i5YQ2`? This is a value that I know in my application.

I tried to delete it using `ref.child(userID).child("pending").child(otherID).removeValue();`, where `userID` is the logged-in user and `otherID` is the identifier for another user. This is basically for accepting or declining friend requests.

I know a solution would be to programmatically set the key as the `otherID` but I really don't want to repeat myself and have the key be the same as the value.

I am retrieving the IDs in `pending` like this

```
  ValueEventListener pendingIdValListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            pendingUserIDs.clear();
            //check to see if firebase returned anything
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                pending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                noPending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                //iterate through each child returned
                for (DataSnapshot e : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //holds the event ID as a string
                    String event = e.getValue(String.class);
                    //adds it to the list
                    pendingUserIDs.add(event);
                }
                //notifies the adapter of any changes
                pendingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            //no pending requests, show a message and hide recycler
            else
            {
                pending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                noPending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
        {
        }
    };
```

Comment: So what is issue with above code ?

Comment: The issue is that in my application I have the value `KX1UfoLwTQOGTFHxyguqcl7i5YQ2` but `child()` expects `0` in order to work.

Comment: Please provide full code where you retrieve all the pending list of users. That's what i am asking

Comment: I posted it. I think I might be using the wrong data structure. I just realized using a map would be better?

Comment: Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your actual database schema, it's not possible to query the elements using that UID, because that UID is apart of an array. However, there is a workaround that implies a change in the database. That being said, a more likely structure that you should use, might look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- User
       |
       --- uid
            |
            --- email: "someemail12@gmail.com"
            |
            --- //Other properties
            |
            --- pending:
                  |
                  --- "KX1U...5YQ2": true
                  |
                  --- "MRGY...46MX": true
```

> How can I delete the node that corresponds to the value KX1UfoLwTQOGTFHxyguqcl7i5YQ2? This is a value that I know in my application.

Now, to get only the users who have in the pending node the `KX1UfoLwTQOGTFHxyguqcl7i5YQ2` and delete it, please use the following lines of code:

```
String loggedInUserUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
String uidToRemove = "KX1UfoLwTQOGTFHxyguqcl7i5YQ2";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference loggedInUserUidRef = rootRef.child("User").child(loggedInUserUid);
Query uidQuery = loggedInUserUidRef.orderByChild("pending/" + uidToRemove).equalTo(true);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("pending/" + uidToRemove).getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
uidQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The above lines of code will remove the UID that exists under the "pending" node.

If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), please note that the operation that you are looking for is actually possible:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership